# Can't call playerprefs on other scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

so I'm here want to retrieve the string to text in a different scene with, but after I've tried by my self isn't working, am I do it wrong?

here the google sign script in that script I want to save the string `task.result.displayName` with `Playerprefs`

```
internal void OnAuthenticationFinished(Task<GoogleSignInUser> task)
{
    if (task.IsFaulted)
    {
        using (IEnumerator<Exception> enumerator = task.Exception.InnerExceptions.GetEnumerator())
        {
            if (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                GoogleSignIn.SignInException error = (GoogleSignIn.SignInException)enumerator.Current;
                AddToInformation("Got Error: " + error.Status + " " + error.Message);
            }
            else
            {
                AddToInformation("Got Unexpected Exception?!?" + task.Exception);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (task.IsCanceled)
    {
        AddToInformation("Canceled");
    }
    else
    {

        AddToInformation("Welcome: " + task.Result.DisplayName + "!");
        AddToInformation("Email = " + task.Result.Email);
        AddToInformation("Google ID Token = " + task.Result.IdToken);
        AddToInformation("Email = " + task.Result.Email);
        SignInWithGoogleOnFirebase(task.Result.IdToken);

        currEmail = task.Result.DisplayName;
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("Username " + currEmail, currEmail);
        Debug.Log(currEmail);
    }
private void AddToInformation(string str) { infoText.text += "\n" + str; }
```

after that, I want to call the `Playerprefs.GetString` to another scene with attaching on text

```
 void Start()
{
    displayName();
}

public void displayName()
{
    userName.text = PlayerPrefs.GetString("Username " + googleSign.currEmail + "Username ");
}
```

but why that doesn't work, for your info I don't use `DontDestroyOnload on google sign script so I attach on a sign in the scene and main menu scene`

Comment: First debug the values of the googleSign.currEmail if they are the same. The variable resets when you load a new scene. Make the currEmail variable static and see if it will hold the value.

Answer (score 0):

Call

```
PlayerPrefs.Save();
```

after your SetString method to save data in prefs

Check if googleSign.currEmail has value in debug, also you get your string wrong, it should be

```
PlayerPrefs.GetString("Username " + googleSign.currEmail)
```

Without

```
+ "Username "
```

at the end

Comment: `currEmail = task.Result.DisplayName;

            PlayerPrefs.SetString("Username " + currEmail, currEmail);
            PlayerPrefs.Save(); `

like that ?

Comment: yes, when you just set string your data do not save

Comment: Thank you, I have tried it but it still doesn't work